# Instantiate Dictionary<T, U> in Java error

Tags: java, generics, dictionary

In C#

```
Dictionary<String, String> dictionary = new Dictionary<String, String>();
```

In Java, this errors with

> Cannot instantiate the type
>   Dictionary

What could be wrong?

In my code this follows with

```
dictionary.put("vZip", jsonUdeals.getString("vZip"));
```

I know this sounds too trivial. But I am at a loss!
If Dictionary doesn't do it(which I strongly suspect by now), then which DataStructure to use.

Comment: First rule of Java programming: if you have problems with a specific class or method in the standard API, read the API doc before doing anything else.

Comment: thanks mate. IMHO that goes for C# too. :) I have indeed looked into it. Its just that I overlooked the word abstract in the definition. C# also has Dictionary<T,U> which aint abstract at all. Plus, I am familiarizing the Eclipse IDE also

Answer (score 76, accepted):

[`Dictionary`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Dictionary.html) is an abstract class in Java.  It is also obsolete; you should use the `Map` interface instead; something like:

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

Note that [`HashMap<K,V>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is a concrete class, but we're assigning it to a [`Map<K,V>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) reference, which is an interface.  This is the recommended style in Java, because it allows you to switch `HashMap` for e.g. `Hashtable` at a later stage, without having to change everything.

Comment: foraying into java from C# and i like what i see :)

Comment: @naveen: Pretty soon you'll be dismayed by e.g. how rubbish Java generics are, and the lack of operator overloading, etc. ... !

Comment: I read Jon Skeet a lot and so I know :) I like the Eclipse IDE tons better than Visual Studio though. refactoring is another level altogether

Comment: @naveen: You are the first person I've heard of that likes Eclipse more than Visual Studio.  I like open source in general, but Visual Studio is by far the nicest IDE I've used.  Although I do hope Eclipse will reach that level someday.

Answer (score 4):

Use a HashMap as follows:

```
Map<String, String> dictionary = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary is a abstract class, use [Hashtable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html)

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary is  a legacy class. The same thing can be achieved with hashmap or 
concurrentHashMap(if synchronization is required Java 8)